# regex for time validation Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 18

Tags: php, regex, datetime, time

```
 preg_match("/([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?/", $time
```

want to preg_match 24 hours

Matching time formats :

```
01:00, 02:00, 13:00,
 1:00,  2:00, 13:01,
23:59, 15:00,
00:00,  0:00,
14:34:43, 01:00:00
```

Not matching time formats :

```
24:00             # hour is out of range [0-23]
 12:60             # minute is out of range [00-59]
  0:0              # invalid format for minute, at least 2 digits
 13:1              # invalid format for minute, at least 2 digits
  0:00:0           # invalid format for seconds, at least 2 digits
101:00             # hour is out of range [0-23]
```

but on

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:25'));    // OK
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '25:25'));    // KO
```

I got Error

```
 Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 18 in C:\xampp\htdocs\march\admin\test.php on line 8
bool(false) 0:00 - No
```

Comment: `~^([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d(:[0-5]\d)?$~` (shorter for 9 characters).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an open parentheses.

```
var_dump(preg_match('#^[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:25'));
//                     ^ here
var_dump(preg_match('#^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?$#', '14:25'));
```